# Preferred Fragment lifecycle method for instantiating ViewModels

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-livedata

In the [android-architecture-components/GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/9acce5ead48dc94539d8f897fddc5a64f33f7eab/GithubBrowserSample) repo, the `Fragment#onViewCreated` lifecycle method is being used for `ViewModel` instantiation (with the *`Fragment`'s* scope) for the `Fragment`s that use the combination of databinding + `LiveData` + `ViewModel`:

From `SearchFragment.kt` of that repo ^:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        searchViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
        ...
    }
```

Is there any official guideline or consensus as to which of these `Fragment` lifecycle methods such as `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onViewCreated`, or `onActivityCreated` is the best/safest place to instantiate the `Fragment`'s `ViewModel` using the `ViewModelProviders.of(fragment, viewModelFactory)` method? (given the databinding + `LiveData` combo, if that makes a difference)

Trying to make sense of the general advantages/disadvantages of putting `ViewModel` instantiation into any of the early lifecycle methods such as `onAttach`/`onCreate`, for example (after calling `super`, of course).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no such rule. I am using `lazy`  on mines

Comment: IMO you can initialize Viewmodel in `onCreate`. You would be observing on `onViewCreated` anyways.

Answer (score 6):

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    searchViewModel = ViewModelProvider().get(this, viewModelFactory)
```

This is correct, the common mistake tends to be the lifecycle owner used to observe the LiveData.

```
    // also in onViewCreated
    searchViewModel.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { items ->
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct advantage of one to another as far as I know, since #onViewCreated is immediately being called after #onCreateView finishes. According to the docs:

> void onViewCreated (View view, 
>                   Bundle savedInstanceState)
>
> Called immediately after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup,
>   Bundle) has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in
>   to the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves
>   once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. The
>   fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at
>   this point.

I normally prefer putting all initializations (if not related to my view-hierarchy) into #onViewCreated method. It has never been a problem in my case.

Comment: awesome, thanks! yeah, it sounds like it's just about picking one of them and being consistent with it throughout one's codebase.